# How do I match an Index in 1 list with a different list index value and output the 2nd list values?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to match a value in one list to a value in another list if a condition is met. I'd like the target list to be the values from list2 where the corresponding element in list1 is 1, then output this to a new list.

```
binaryList = []
binaryWeight = [128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

while len(binaryList) < 8:
    digit = int(input('Please enter digit: '))

for i in range(len(binaryList)):
    if i == 1:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as my head is fried trying to think of a solution after hours of tinkering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you've created `binaryList` as `[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]` like you've indicated.

Think about what's actually happening in your `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(binaryList)):
```

`i` is going to be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, so `i == 1` will only happen one time in that loop.

What you're actually trying to do is see if the **value** of `binaryList` is 1.  There are a couple of ways to do this.

First, you could access the value of `binaryList` at the index `i` like this:

```
for i in range(len(binaryList)):
   if binaryList[i] == 1:
```

Or you can use the handy `enumerate()` method, which provides both the index and the value of an iterable.

```
for index, value in enumerate(binaryList):
    if value == 1:
```

Next, I'm assuming you want to create a new list based on the values in `binaryWeights`.  Let's just call that `newList` (and make sure you define it earlier in your code like you did with `binaryList`.  Then you can do the following:

```
for index, value in enumerate(binaryList):
    if value == 1:
        newList.append(binaryWeights[index])
```

Notice that we use the `index` to access the value of the position in `binaryWeights` that matches the position of the `value` 1 in `binaryList`.  Also note that you don't need to have an `else` with an `if` statement.  Python will just ignore cases that don't match the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most starightforward way to do this is using a small list comprehension. You can use [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) to iterate over values and indices at the same time.

```
binaryList = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
binaryWeights = [32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

[binaryWeights[i] for i,b in enumerate(binaryList) if b]
# [32, 8, 1]
```